# How to submit arrays without keys via php curl?

Tags: php, arrays, multipartform-data, php-curl

I need to submit various fields via curl request. Some fields are simple types like strings or integers, some are files and some are arrays.
The target server is not able to accept array fields in case of submitting with keys in field name. They should be submitted with fieldnames like `fieldname[]` and NOT via `fieldname[0]`.

From the docs i got this working example:

```
curl -H "Authorization: __TOKEN__" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Extended-errors: true" -X POST \
    -F 'foo[field_a]=Dev' \ 
    -F 'foo[field_b]=https://example.org' \
    -F 'foo[field_c][]=bar1' \
    -F 'foo[field_c][]=bar2' \
    -F 'foo[field_c][]=bar3' \
    -F 'foo[field_d]=@/path/to/file.jpg' -g -v \
    "https://api.example.com/endpoint"
```

I need to do this via PHP using the curl extension and tried this:

```
$url = 'https://api.example.com/endpoint';

$fields = [
    'foo[field_a]' => 'Dev',
    'foo[field_b]' => 'https://example.org',
    'foo[field_c][0]' => 'bar1',
    'foo[field_c][1]' => 'bar2',
    'foo[field_c][2]' => 'bar3',
    'foo[field_d]' => new CURLFile('/path/to/file.jpg'),
];


$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

As you can see i had do use indexes for `field_c` because i cannot define `foo[field_c][]` twice in `$fields` array. In case of having just one item in array it works with key `foo[field_c][]`!
However, `foo[field_c][0]` does not work for the target server. I don't know if this is a bug or not but it is the case. If i do it this way from command line it fails, too.
If I use no indexes it works. So I need to be able to send arrays like this `fieldname[]` via php.

I also tried to define `foo` as full array and set the postfields via `http_build_query($fields)`. But with the same result because `http_build_query` creates fieldnames with indexes, too.

Is there some way to send array fields without an index via php curl?
Is this remote hosts behaviour a bug? I.e. it is somewhere specified in specs that the server should accept arrays with keys?

Comment: have you tried with array_merge(field_a, field_b, field_c, field_d)?

Comment: @GiacomoM i do not know what you are trying to do with `array_merge` but maybe you should write an answer and explain it.

Comment: with array_merge you can create the array foo[field_c] without index (even if php creates numeric index anyway), and maybe your code works.